# SQLHelper.vb missing ExecuteDataTable

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

Why is there no Shared function for ExecuteDataTable in [SQLHelper.vb](https://appsimplicity.googlecode.com/svn-history/r217/MetaDataExtractor/SchemaDiscovery/AppSimplicity.SchemaDiscovery.Providers/SQLServer/DataAccess/SQLHelper.vb).  There is an: ExecuteReader, ExecuteDataset and ExecuteScaler.

This is not a problem as I will write my own.  I am just wandering why this is the case.  I would normally use a DataReader but I am writing a data logic layer and the DataTable needs to outlive the connection (DataReaders cannot outlive a connection).

Answer (score 1):

`ExecuteDataset()` will already do what you need. A dataset is, in one sense, just a collection of DataTables.

> I would normally use a DataReader but I am writing a data logic layer and the DataTable needs to outlive the connection (DataReaders cannot outlive a connection).

In this case, may I suggest that instead of building an ExecuteDatatable() method, you build an `ExecuteEnumerable()` method that uses a DataReader in an Iterator block. The code would look something like this:

```
Public Shared Iterator Function ExecuteEnumerable(Of T)( ... ) As IEnumerable(Of T)
   Using cn As New SqlConnection( ... ), _
         cmd As New SqlCommand( ... )

       'As needed
       'cmd.Parameters.Add( ... ).Value = ...

       Using rdr As SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
           While rdr.Read()
               Yield transform(rdr)
           End While
       End Using
    End Using
End Function
```

You'll notice that I skipped over a few things. I'm not familiar with the existing SqlHelper.vb file, and as you would want to match existing style I left room in the code for you to adapt for that. However, there are two important pieces I want to call out:

1. Note the cmd.Parameters.Add() call. One common failing of utility sql help classes is that they fail to adequately provide for query parameters. All to often the result is horribly insecure code. If you don't have a way right now to pass parameter data for your existing methods, you need to make one. That is priority 1.
2. The `transform(rdr)` call there will use a `Func(IDataRecord, T)` delegate that must be supplied as an argument to the function. For the ExecuteEnumerable() iterator concept to work, you *must* take a copy of the current values in the SqlDataReader object on each iteration. You could set up some kind of generic data transfer object here, as is done with the DataRow type using in a DataTable. However, rather than spending cpu and memory time creating a copy into a generic data transport object of some type, I prefer to use a delegate to have the code copy it directly into a strongly-typed business object. The downside is needing to send instructions on how to do that for your specific object with every call to method. Most often, though, this is easy enough to do with a shared factory method on your business object.

Comment: Thanks. I am using .NET 3.5 and VS 2008. I don't believe I can use Yield.  Is there a reason not to iterate through DataTables?

Comment: Just to avoid bringing the whole result set into memory at once.

Comment: Is this solution is still viable for .NET 3.5?

Answer (score 0):

We can create same as DataSet like

```
' Execute a SqlCommand (that returns a resultset) against the specified SqlConnection 
' using the provided parameters.
' e.g.:  
' Dim dt As DataTable = ExecuteDataTable(conn, CommandType.StoredProcedure, "GetOrders", new SqlParameter("@prodid", 24))
' Parameters:
' -connection - a valid SqlConnection
' -commandType - the CommandType (stored procedure, text, etc.)
' -commandText - the stored procedure name or T-SQL command
' -commandParameters - an array of SqlParamters used to execute the command
' Returns: A dataset containing the resultset generated by the command
Public Overloads Shared Function ExecuteDataTable(ByVal connection As SqlConnection, _
                                                ByVal commandType As CommandType, _
                                                ByVal commandText As String, _
                                                ByVal ParamArray commandParameters() As SqlParameter) As DataTable
    If (connection Is Nothing) Then Throw New ArgumentNullException("connection")
    ' Create a command and prepare it for execution
    Dim cmd As New SqlCommand
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    Dim dataAdatpter As SqlDataAdapter
    Dim mustCloseConnection As Boolean = False

    PrepareCommand(cmd, connection, CType(Nothing, SqlTransaction), commandType, commandText, commandParameters, mustCloseConnection)

    Try
        ' Create the DataAdapter & DataSet
        dataAdatpter = New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)

        ' Fill the DataSet using default values for DataTable names, etc
        dataAdatpter.Fill(dt)

        ' Detach the SqlParameters from the command object, so they can be used again
        cmd.Parameters.Clear()
    Finally
        If (Not dataAdatpter Is Nothing) Then dataAdatpter.Dispose()
    End Try
    If (mustCloseConnection) Then connection.Close()

    ' Return the dataset
    Return dt
End Function ' ExecuteDataTable
```